# Scrolling impossible while moving mouse - Fedora 28 VM guest on Win10

Tags: fedora, windows, virtual-machine, mouse, peripherals

I have been searching awhile before asking my question here, but still cannot find any answer.

I have noticed that mouse scrolling is generally poorly handled on Linux (maybe just Gnome tho).

I am running my Fedora 28 on a VirtualBox VM, under a Windows 10 host.
I noticed that scrolling using mouse wheel works perfectly when mouse is immobile, but whenever I start moving it, scroll doesn't work at all until mouse gets immobile again.

Does any of you know how to make it work even while moving the mouse ?
Am I missing some configuration or something ?

I must confess I am not a solid Linux user and I don't know much about peripherals configuration.

Comment: I don't seem to have that problem in fedora.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I obviously forgot to mention I am under a VM on a Win10 host.

Comment: I also run some Fedora VMs under W10 and do not have this problem, but I also do not use Gnome 3, so you can try another DE if you do not have to use Gnome 3.

Comment: Thanks @ajeh, I'll try another one and report if it works better.

Comment: I noticed this the first time back in the days of the free VMware Server 2.0 with some Gnome 2 Linux. It happens to me now on many Windows computers, both with VMware and VirtualBox, also with Mate, Unity or KDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered this thread
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=223470

Basically if I run `xev | grep -e "ButtonPress" -e "ButtonRelease"` and move the mouse over the window while scrolling I can clearly see the events, which means it's a desktop environment / window manager problem.

People discussing more about the issue here https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-libinput/issues/9

If I simply launch `firefox` from a terminal, I experience scroll events being ignored while moving the mouse, but if I do instead a `GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS=1 firefox` then everything works as expected.

The thread at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=79002&start=15 contains a more interesting reply from a bugmenot user:

Running `xinput` should show the devices X believes are sending events:

```bsh
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox USB Tablet                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Apparently mouse events are divided between the `VirtualBox mouse integration` and the `VirtualBox USB Tablet` device. One of them receives the movement events while the other the scroll events. In some applications once a source of events becomes active, the other one is ignored.

The solution is to disable `VirtualBox mouse integration` (id=9 in my listing above) either temporarily with

```bsh
xinput disable 9
```

or completely by adding a file, for example `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vbox-mouse-fix.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Fix VBox scroll wheel"
        MatchProduct "VirtualBox mouse integration"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

(the `MatchProduct` directive is exactly the string output from `xinput`).

Answer (score 1):

installing **imwheel** package fixed my problem.

yum install imwheel (fedora)

Comment: This was the only thing that fixed it for me after uninstalling/reinstalling guest additions, changing mouse settings in VirtualBox and trying the above.  Works like a charm now.