# Is it possible to combine two pointer xinput devices into a single device?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, mouse, xinput, input-method

I'm using VirtualBox and it comes with a "Mouse Integration" feature, which creates a 2nd pointer input called `VirtualBox mouse integration` aside from the existing pointer input.

```bsh
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This thread has a lot more detail about this "multiple cursor inputs in VirtualBox" issue: [Scrolling impossible while moving mouse - Fedora 28 VM guest on Win10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446314/scrolling-impossible-while-moving-mouse-fedora-28-vm-guest-on-win10)

According to that thread, `VirtualBox mouse integration` receives only movement events while the other device only receives scroll events. As a result, **scrolling does not work when the mouse is moving**, as many programs only allow one active input device at a time.

Is it possible combine these two input devices into one "virtual" input device, so that desktop programs can use that device as the active input device?

Mouse input events can be checked with:

```
xinput test-xi2 --root
```

On my machine it clearly shows mouse position and scroll events being sent by different devices:

```
EVENT type 17 (RawMotion)
    device: 2 (9)
    detail: 0
    flags: 
    valuators:
          0: 1704.97 (1704.97)
          1: 39323.40 (39323.40)

EVENT type 6 (Motion)
    device: 9 (9)
    detail: 0
    flags: 
    root: 55.23/570.23
    event: 55.23/570.23
    buttons:
    modifiers: locked 0x10 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0x10
    group: locked 0 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0
    valuators:
        0: 1704.97
        1: 39323.40
    windows: root 0x532 event 0x532 child 0x4600003
EVENT type 17 (RawMotion)
    device: 2 (12)
    detail: 0
    flags: 
    valuators:
          3: 15.00 (15.00)

EVENT type 6 (Motion)
    device: 12 (12)
    detail: 0
    flags: 
    root: 55.23/571.23
    event: 55.23/571.23
    buttons:
    modifiers: locked 0x10 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0x10
    group: locked 0 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0
    valuators:
        3: -1470.00
    windows: root 0x532 event 0x532 child 0x4600003
EVENT type 15 (RawButtonPress)
    device: 2 (12)
    detail: 5
    flags: emulated
    valuators:

EVENT type 4 (ButtonPress)
    device: 12 (12)
    detail: 5
    flags: emulated
    root: 55.23/571.23
    event: 55.23/571.23
    buttons:
    modifiers: locked 0x10 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0x10
    group: locked 0 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0
    valuators:
    windows: root 0x532 event 0x532 child 0x4600003
EVENT type 16 (RawButtonRelease)
    device: 2 (12)
    detail: 5
    flags: emulated
    valuators:

EVENT type 5 (ButtonRelease)
    device: 12 (12)
    detail: 5
    flags: emulated
    root: 55.23/571.23
    event: 55.23/571.23
    buttons: 5
    modifiers: locked 0x10 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0x10
    group: locked 0 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0
    valuators:
    windows: root 0x532 event 0x532 child 0x4600003
```

Comment: Devices are listed in /dev/input, I need a way to either combine devices there, or create a new device that uses inputs from other devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, as it will need coding with *libevdev*, but it should be possible to "grab" for exclusive reading each of the two input devices, and create a new Uinput virtual device combining the events from them into a single stream.  There are separate C examples of reading events and writing events available, but this Python single-page [tutorial](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) has many interesting building-block example parts (same url, different points in page):

1. Reading events from multiple devices [here](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events-from-multiple-devices-using-select)
2. Getting exclusive access to a device [here](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#getting-exclusive-access-to-a-device)
3. Create uinput device with capabilities of another device [here](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#create-uinput-device-with-capabilities-of-another-device)
4. Injecting input [here](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#injecting-input)

There is a Rust program [evsieve](https://github.com/KarsMulder/evsieve), that can do a lot of merging and mapping of evdev devices. You should check out if it can be configured to do what you need.

Comment: I checked out evsieve but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, the command `sudo evsieve --input /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-1-event-mouse grab --input /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:04.0-event-mouse grab --print --output create-link=/dev/input/by-id/host-mouse` indeed grabs both mouse inputs, but I am unable to move my cursor despite it printing mouse absolute position events. I'll try using libevdev and write a script later to verify