# How to use two mice at the same time (single pointer)

Tags: mouse, input, libinput

I'm on Xorg (using libinput). I'm trying two use two "mouse" devices, one for scrolling and the other for moving the cursor. But when the pointer is moving, some aplications (but not `libinput debug-events`) seem to be ignoring the scroll events from the other device (for example Firefox, Blender and GNOME Shell react normally, but GTK/Electron applications don't react the scrolling events).

This somehow seems like a "feature", but I can't find a single information on the topic.

Comment: You might want to check this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668318/is-it-possible-to-combine-two-pointer-xinput-devices-into-a-single-device

Answer (score 1):

So after many hours of searching, this does not seem to be something new, and some issues related to it date back to a decade ago.

But simply running `imwheel` seems to solve the issue.

Thanks to @Eduardo Trápani's comment of referring to another issue, one can also use something like the following to map two devices as one and solve the issue:

```
sudo evsieve --input <device> grab --input <device2> grab --output create-link=/dev/input/by-id/host-mouse
```

But this doesn't work if some events are sent via XTest rather than a physical input device.