# Can I merge keyboard and mouse to a single virtual input device?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, wayland, input-method, libinput

There are some applications that use strange/inconvenient user interaction and that is impossible to edit. I want to remap a combination of a keyboard and mouse event to another combination of keyboard and mouse event.

To be precise, I want such map `ctrl` + `wheel up`  -> `alt` + `wheel up` to be activated when a specified application (davinci resolve) is in focus.

There is [imwheel](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IMWheel) utility that solves exactly this task. But that utility is very outdated and targeted for X11, while I am looking for a solution for Wayland. As additonlal note, despite my current use case allows to use it (because davinci resolve currently only runs via Xwayland), it is working not so great. Sometimes several events are not "translated", which leads to unwanted effects. I hope the new wayland supporting utilities will not have such problem.

I have found a very [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/668318/264065), but for two mice, and it had not exact answer.

I have found utilities ([pronobis fork of evdevremapkeys](https://github.com/pronobis/evdevremapkeys) or [evremap](https://github.com/wez/evremap)) that potentially can serve this task, as they allow N:N mappings. But the config file for them uses only one device (at the moment of writing at least), see [here](https://github.com/wez/evremap/issues/14).

Now I got an idea to create a virtual evdev input device from my keyboard and mouse (in other words, merge them), and use it in the utility's config. Is it possible?

I have a strong feeling that it may be possible with [python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) or [evsieve](https://github.com/KarsMulder/evsieve).
But I do not know what exactly should I do to make such virtual input device.

Comment: I read as part of the link you provided "see here" that you found *imwheel* that would functionally answer your need (as far as I understand it, it actually would) but that you are in search of a solution compatible with a wayland backend. If my reading is correct (in short that in fact you are searching a wayland compatible imwheel), could you be explicit about that in your question here please.

Comment: Instead of creating a virtual device, you might find that [Input Remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/) allows you to do what you want.

Comment: @StephenKitt I saw Input Remapper, but I could not find a way to map multi-device event. Maybe I am missing it. Can you show how to do it?

Comment: I wasn’t sure, thanks for giving it a shot! I see you found a nice solution.

Comment: @StephenKitt It is half-solution, I now need to map exactly wheel event. 
Buy the way, Input Remapper does not list that "Evsieve Virtual Device" for some reason.

Comment: For Input Remapper to see the new device, I used `--output create-link=/dev/input/by-id/merged-virtual-KM name="merged virtual KM"`

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully created a merged device with the following command (with help of [documentation](https://github.com/KarsMulder/evsieve#process-two-devices-simultaneously)):

```
$ evsieve --input /dev/input/event8 grab --input /dev/input/event5 grab --output
```

Where `/dev/input/event8` is my keyboard, `/dev/input/event5` is my mouse. And that created `/dev/input/event3` with name `Evsieve Virtual Device`.

For the actual remap `ctrl` + `wheel` to `alt` + `wheel` and  `alt` + `wheel` to `ctrl` + `wheel` we can change the command to the following (taken from [here](https://github.com/KarsMulder/evsieve/issues/18#issuecomment-1164685005)):

```bash
sudo evsieve --input /dev/input/event8 grab --input /dev/input/event5 grab \
    --hook   key:leftalt:1 toggle=alt:2 \
    --hook   key:leftalt:0 toggle=alt:1 \
    --hook   key:leftctrl:1 toggle=ctrl:2 \
    --hook   key:leftctrl:0 toggle=ctrl:1 \
    --toggle rel:wheel @alt-up @alt-down id=alt \
    --map    yield rel:wheel@alt-down key:leftalt:0 key:leftctrl:1 key:leftctrl:2 rel:wheel key:leftctrl:0 key:leftalt:1 \
    --toggle rel:wheel @ctrl-up @ctrl-down id=ctrl \
    --map    yield rel:wheel@ctrl-down key:leftctrl:0 key:leftalt:1 key:leftalt:2 rel:wheel key:leftalt:0 key:leftctrl:1 \
    --block  rel:wheel_hi_res \
    --print  @alt-down @alt-up @ctrl-down @ctrl-up \
    --output create-link=/dev/input/by-id/merged-virtual-KM name="merged virtual KM"
```

If want to use evremap, we can use the following config:

```
device_name = "Evsieve Virtual Device"

[[remap]]
input = ["KEY_LEFTALT", "BTN_RIGHT"]
output = ["KEY_PAGEUP"]
```

Pressing Alt + right mouse button moved my cursor up, i.e. generated PgUp. But mapping a wheel event is [currently](https://github.com/wez/evremap/issues/14) impossible.

Comment: Superb ! Congrats !