# Cannot scroll while moving mouse in Ubuntu VirtualBox guest

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, mouse, xinput, peripherals

Applications in Ubuntu, such as Chromium or the GNOME Terminal, are not responsive to mouse wheel scroll events when moving the mouse cursor at the same time. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS as guest OS using VirtualBox 6.1 with a Windows 10 host.

I am facing the exact same problem, as described in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446314/scrolling-impossible-while-moving-mouse-fedora-28-vm-guest-on-win10/). I have tried to apply its accepted solution but it is not working: When running `xev | grep -e "ButtonPress" -e "ButtonRelease"`, I can see that scrolling events are indeed recorded while moving the mouse cursor.

I am also getting the exact same output with `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox USB Tablet                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

However, while disabling `VirtualBox mouse integration` with `xinput disable 9`, as suggested by the accepted solution, does make my applications more responsive to mouse wheel scroll events, it also has the undesirable side effect of disabling mouse pointer movement altogether (clicking still works though).